# How to get access to local network of remote server via iptables

Tags: linux, networking, iptables

I have 2 linux servers with public IPs. On one of the servers(for example A-server) i have configured VPN via ipsec which have access to some private network (10.0.0.0/16). My question is following: how i can configure (via iptables) access from second server (B-server) to private netowrk of A-server? I know it's possible to do via NAT and ip route, but im not familiar with this such well as i should. And i know that easiest way is VPN configuration on B-server, but B-server has outdated OS and IKEv2 ipsec connection is not configurable :(

Server A:

- public IP 1.2.3.4 on `eth0`
- VPN IP 10.0.0.1 on `ipsec0`

Server B:

- public IP 1.2.3.5 on `eth0`

Please help me and give the advice which rules i should add on A and B servers for access from B-server to local network of A server.

Note: Unfortunatelly there is no private network between both servers A and B

Comment: The question is unclear as you don't describe your existing structure in detail, but if you have a VPN between server A and server B, and both servers act as gateways for their "private network", you need routing information (e.g. via `ip route`) and not `iptables`.

Comment: hi @dirkt, thanks for the answer here. My structure is following:

1) Old server (B server) with some public IP x.x.x.x . 
2) New server (A server) with sone public IP y.y.y.y and ipsec configuration to some private network 10.0.0.0/8.

Unfortunatelly these two servers are not contacting via VPN or private network :(

Comment: @dirkt so my main issue is - i need to have access to private network of new server from old one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood the question properly, you can achieve this in two ways: 
1- Entirely with routing
2- Using NAT

**Routing only method**

From Server A's perspective, both networks are directly connected, hence no iptables forwarding rules are required here.

On Server A:

Enable IP forwarding by adding `net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1` in `/etc/sysctl.conf` and apply it with `sysctl -p /etc/sysctl.conf`.

On Server B:

Add a route for the private IP block towards Server A: `route add -net 10.0.0.0/16 gw 1.2.3.4`.

**NAT method**

In this method, you can NAT private IPs at Server A using iptables `nat` table:

`iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE`

OR

`iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -s 10.0.0.0/16 -j SNAT --to-source 1.2.3.4`

Then, add any rules required to forward traffic between two interfaces in iptables `filter` table and enable ip forwarding in `sysctl`.

In this method however, a connection between Server B & a private IP device should always be initiated from private IP side (due to many-to-one NAT aka PAT). If you need to have one-to-one NAT, you will need a pool of public IPs.

Comment: hi @Chaminda, thanks for the reply. i did this via iptables on server-A and route on server B  :)

Answer (score 0):

The setup is still not clear. Please edit question as required.

Assuming you have server A and server B connected by a VPN with the following configuration:

Server A:

- public IP 1.2.3.4 on `eth0`
- VPN IP 10.0.0.1 on `vpn0`
- private network behind server A on 192.168.10.1/24 at `eth1`, with server A acting as gateway

Server B:

- public IP 1.2.3.4 on `eth0`
- VPN IP 10.0.0.2 on `vpn0`
- private network behind server A on 192.168.20.1/24 at `eth1`, with server B acting as gateway

Then you need to set routes e.g. as `ip route add 192.168.20.0/24 via 192.168.20.1 dev eth1` on Server A, and `ip route add 192.168.10.0/24 via 192.168.10.1 dev eth1` on Server B.

Verify with `ip route get <dest-addr>` and `ping` (if necessary, `ping -I ...`), first on both servers, then on machines behind the servers. Use `tcpdump -ni eth1` etc. to see how far the pings get.

**Edit**

Ok, it looks like you **don't** have a VPN between servers A and B, and the "private network" you want to access is not behind server A, but is actually the VPN, with a private IP address range.

And this won't work: You can't route private IP destinations via the public internet. Nor can you use `iptables` to do this.

So you need **some** kind of tunnel between Server A and Server B. Even if Server B has an outdated OS without configurable IPsec tunnel, there are plenty of other options (Tinc, OpenVPN, even an unecnrypted `ip gre` tunnel which already worked 20 years ago...).

So find out what kind of tunnels Server B supports. Then establish a tunnel (encrypted or unencrypted) between Server A and Server B, and proceed as described above.

Comment: Hi @dirkt . Setup is following:

Server A :

- public IP 1.2.3.4 on `eth0`
- VPN IP 10.0.0.1 on `ipsec0` (VPN conecting Server A and 3rd-party network and not related to Server B)

Server B: 
- public IP 1.2.3.5 on `eth0`

Unfortunatelly there is no private network between both servers or VPN configured. As i discribed bellow in issue - server B is running on outdated OS and there is no way to configure VPN between A and B

Comment: Hi @dirkt. thanks for the answer. i did this via iptables on server-A and routing on server-B ) Now i have access to private network of Server-A on Server-B

Comment: Note that you are not doing "iptables routing" (for some reason people think they need to use iptables for routing, which is nonsense, and a pet peeve of mine), you are doing NAT (network address translation), which is a completely different thing, and only will allow access in one direction.

Answer (score 0):

If you *really* mean public IP when you said public IP, instead of private IP in a Ethernet LAN (i.e. just not a *virtual private* network, a.k.a VPN), then you most likely have to set up some sort of VPN. While you say Server B has an outdated OS blah blah, it doesn't even have to be (in fact, better not) to be the VPN server. You merely need to set up *another* VPN server on Server A, just for Server B as the client.

If A and B are actually in the same LAN, such that A can be a gateway for B (which basically means that you can locate A from B with ARP and do layer 2 switching between them, AFAIK), you can add the following route on B:

```
ip route add 10.0.0.0/16 via 1.2.3.4 dev eth0 src 1.2.3.5
```

(The `dev` and `src` parts are optional and may even not be desirable in some cases, AFAIK)

---

If Server A is the VPN server and the default gateway of `10.0.0.0/16`, then you don't need to do anything further in terms of route. If it is not, then you need to add return route to the default gateway or any hosts that need to be accessible by/via Server B.

```
ip route add 1.2.3.5 via 10.0.0.1
```

Further configuration might be needed when Server A is not the VPN server but a client of `10.0.0.0/16`, like for example for OpenVPN you need to add `iroute`.

---

If you want to avoid adding return route, or for whatever reason you need to "masquerade" Server B as Server A to the hosts in 10.0.0.0/16, you can use `MASQUERADE` or `SNAT` of iptables:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 1.2.3.5 -o ipsec0 -d 10.0.0.0/16 -j MASQUERADE
```

or

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 1.2.3.5 -o ipsec0 -d 10.0.0.0/16 -j SNAT --to-source 1.2.3.4
```

The `-s` and `-d` parts are optional, just to refine to rule so that either of them applies only to traffics from B to `10.0.0.0/16`. (Especially `-d`, as you probably want to simply limit forwarding to specific destination with rules in the `filter` table instead anyway. The `-s` part avoid the masquerading from applying to sources that don't need it though, so it might be preferable.)

`SNAT` is preferred over `MASQUERADE` if `1.2.3.5` is static for performance reason. Essentially they are equivalent.

---

All of the above assumes that forwarding has already been enabled on Server A and no filter rules are applied for that (more precisely, all forwarding traffics are allowed, that is).

Also the set up applies for Server B itself only. You may need further set up if you are trying to make `10.0.0.0/16` reachable from for example hosts in a VPN that Server B holds.

Comment: The general idea is the same if A and B are interconnected via a VPN btw, just that the details (e.g. addresses, interface names, etc.) will be different.

Comment: hey @tom. Sorry for the delayed reply and thanks for the answer.  i read some iptables docs and did almost the same which you provided me:
i have added below on 1.2.3.4 (server with private VPN network)
```
-A FORWARD -s 1.2.3.5/32 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -d 1.2.3.5/32 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
```
and to the nat i have added MASQUERADE ipsec0 
On the Server-B (with only one public IP) i have add routing to the private network of Server-A via public IP `ip route add 10.0.0.0/16 via 1.2.3.4 dev eth0`
And now i have access to A-VPN on B

Comment: @from_mars For the record, in your case there's almost no point at all to do (S)NAT/masquerade on A (at either `eth0` or `ipsec0`), unless the VPN hosts (or B) have firewall rules that allows only access from their own subnet or so, as apparently A is the VPN server / default gateway of `10.0.0.0/16` so you don't need explicit route to B for the VPN hosts anyway.